# Loading backbone js view iframe inside jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, iframe

I'm creating a view for iframe of my report.

```
<div id="aDialog"></div>
```

Here is **ReportView** :

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone",
],function($, _, Backbone){
  var ReportView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el : "#agingFrame",
     initialize: function() {
         this.$el.html('<iframe src="http://ipadressofreportserver/jasper/blahblah"></iframe>');
     },
     render: function(){
     }
   });
   return ReportView;
});
```

Then I have another view that can let the user print the iframe above, here is the main view action :

```
 'printingReportIcon' : function(){
    var page = "http://localhost/Source/#ReportView";
    var $dialog = $('#aDialog')
            .load(page)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 625,
                width: 500,
                title: "Some title"
            });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

**Problem**

The dialog is opened with all the source code in **ReportView** but no iframe.

Any idea what could be causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i believe that the problem is the ReportView is not been instantiated(renderized) on the second view. You are just getting the relative url for that view, but not render the content.

Try to:

- Use the render method to render the content in ReportView.
- Return this content and use it to open the dialog.

I guess that this is the problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: I moved `this.$el.html('<iframe src...>)` to `render()` method of `ReportView` and put `return this;` after it. But thing still didn't work at all.

Comment: Finally I've done with it, thanks for your answer rcarvalho :)